# how we can optimize sql request to db to avoid extra information and decrease the time response in nested models?

Tags: sql, api, sqlalchemy

We work with SQLalchemy and postgre sql to write api.We have 2 nested models: user and company.

```
class UserBaseModel(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    company:CompanyModel



class CompanyCreateModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
```

```
def get_all_companies(db: Session, name_like: Optional[str]) -> List[Company]:
    query = db.query(Company)
    if name_like:
        query = query.filter(Company.name.ilike(f"%{name_like}%"))
    return query.all()
```

and with this query.all() in response it gives back whole the class of company inside the user but i only need company_id.

I also want to know if it the pydantic model which triggers the sql requests or it's just a filter on results after sending the request to the database.

Comment: Your question is to optimize an unknown query on an unknown database.  Perhaps you could provide more information?

Comment: If you "only need company_id" then try just using `db.query(Company.company_id)` or `db.query(Company.id)` or something like that.